# Spring Config Server Service with Heroku

Tags: heroku, spring-boot, microservices, heroku-api, configserver

I am exploring Heroku. I have a project which has **10 micro services**. One of which is a **configuration server** which takes care of **managing configuration for all services** using git hub.

I want to use Heroku for deploying these services but I am not sure how would my Spring Boot Configuration Server would work as Heroku provides a way to configure each hosted app separately(Can configure DB settings for individual app).

Any suggestions/ thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution to my problem, sharing it for a reference.
Just need to use the addons on Heroku and use the addons config details in any of my config file which can be easily managed by the config server through git.

For an instance, if you are having a addon of Postgres, you would get configuration from Heroku for it(url, username, password etc). Use this information in the configuration file which is being managed by config server.